# Automatic auth linking

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

On our app we are using "One account per email address". We want users to sign up using a specific authentication provider, which we keep track of, and stick with it.

What I've noticed today is that if I log in using a Google or Facebook provider I can then send myself a password reset link to the associated email address, which allows me to use the email/password provider instead.
There is a slight difference in behaviour depending on the first provider:

- If I use Google first, after I use the password reset link I can now user either provider to log in, and both are linked to the same firebase uid. If I debug, I can see both in the providerDetails array on the authData object I get back from Firebase.
- If I use Facebook first, after I use the password link the password provider replaces the Facebook one completely, although it retains the old firebase uid. At this point I can no longer use the Facebook login.

My questions are: is this behaviour intended, and, is there any way to switch it off?

This can cause confusion if say a user logs in using Facebook (which we track) and then later forgets and sends a password reset. It isn't the end of the world because they can carry on using the password login, but it certainly muddies the water.

Thanks

Comment: Nice question, interested in fb staff answer !

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is intentional.

For end users, if they had signed into the app using Google or Facebook, and later they want to recover the password, the most likely reason is they (or an attacker) can not login with that identity provider.

After the user clicks the password reset link, Firebase removes the non-email identity providers to prevent other people from accessing the account silently. If the user still wants to add Facebook/Twitter login, they can do that via manual account linking (if the app supports).

In case the user's email service is the same as identity provider (e.g. @gmail.com users login into the app using Google), Firebase has an optimization to keep the identity provider since there is no security risk.

Comment: One thing to counter this Jin:
What we have found is that users are not clicking the reset link because they can't login using Google/Facebook, but because they forgot which method they used in the first place. So, they can recover that situation using the reset link but it does make it confusing that they switched.

If they genuinely can't log in using Google / Facebook, wouldn't it make more sense that they reset their password at source, rather than switching providers in Firebase?

Comment: To solve the problem of users forgetting the previous login method, FirebaseUI implements the flow of identifier-first, where the user first types their email only and following prompt will be based on the account status (redirect to Google/Facebook, or existing password, or new account sign up).

Comment: If the users can reset password at Google/Facebook etc, they will be able to sign into Firebase once they can access their Google/Facebook accounts. In this case the users do not need to click the reset-password link within the Firebase app.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to any documentation for this identifier-first approach? I haven't come across anything like that in the docs I have read.

Comment: Although the doc from Google Identity Toolkit (https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/account-chooser#email_first) is a bit old, FirebaseUI shares the same flow.